# Need to set height in parent to make inside of the stretched content scrollable

Tags: css, flexbox

I am a Japanese engineer and I am not good at English, sorry.

I want to make the ".main-content" scrollable.

And I made it.

It works properly.

But I have a question.

Why do I have to set `height: 0;` to class ".body".

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      padding: 32px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .heading {
      background-color: cornflowerblue;
    }
    .body {
      display: flex;
      flex-grow: 1;
      height: 0;
    }
    .left-nav {
      flex-basis: 200px;
      max-height: 300px;
      overflow-y: auto;
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
    .left-nav-item, .main-content-item {
      height: 80px;
      width: 80px;
      margin: 8px;
      background-color: lightgray;
    }
    .main-content {
      flex-grow: 1;
      overflow-y: auto;
      background-color: lightsteelblue;
    }
    .footing {
      background-color: lightseagreen;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading">
      heading
    </div>
    <div class="body">
      <div class="left-nav">
        <div class="left-nav-item">
          left-nav-item1
        </div>
        <div class="left-nav-item">
          left-nav-item2
        </div>
        <div class="left-nav-item">
          left-nav-item3
        </div>
        <div class="left-nav-item">
          left-nav-item4
        </div>
        <div class="left-nav-item">
          left-nav-item5
        </div>
        <div class="left-nav-item">
          left-nav-item6
        </div>
        <div class="left-nav-item">
          left-nav-item7
        </div>
        <div class="left-nav-item">
          left-nav-item8
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-content">
        <div class="main-content-item">
          main-content-item1
        </div>
        <div class="main-content-item">
          main-content-item2
        </div>
        <div class="main-content-item">
          main-content-item3
        </div>
        <div class="main-content-item">
          main-content-item4
        </div>
        <div class="main-content-item">
          main-content-item5
        </div>
        <div class="main-content-item">
          main-content-item6
        </div>
        <div class="main-content-item">
          main-content-item7
        </div>
        <div class="main-content-item">
          main-content-item8
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footing">
      footing
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The ".main-content" is vertically stretched by ".body"s default value, `align-content: stretch`.

But if the inside of the ".main-content" was overflowed, the height of ".main-content" gets bigger.

And, `overflow-y: auto;` doesn't work.

But if I give `height: 0;`(0 is not important. Some value except for auto is needed.)  to class ".body", ".main-content" gets proper height and become scrollable.

It works properly now, but I want to know why I need to give `height: 0;` to class ".body".

Comment: On where? It works properly already, but I want to know why I need to give height: 0; to class ".body". And putting height: "100%"; to class ".body" also works as you say. 0 is not important. Some value except for auto is needed. But I want to know the reason. Why do I have to put height on ".body".

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack overflow!

> The overflow property specifies what should happen if content
>   overflows an element's box

.

This property specifies whether to clip content or to add scrollbars when an element's content is too big to fit in a specified area.

> Note: The overflow property only works for block elements with a
>   specified height.

It's the default behavior of `overflow` , There should me some height beyond that the element should over flow if you didn't give any specific height the content will not overflow.

> In order for overflow to work on an element’s content, the element
>   needs to have a definite measurement, otherwise, the element container
>   will keep on expanding to accommodate as many content elements it can
>   have or no matter the content’s size, but if the container element has
>   a set height or a cap height ( max-height), once its content reaches
>   those limits, it will follow the overflow rule, which in case of
>   scroll, it will hide any content that should be surpassing the height
>   of the container, and it will allow us to see it by dragging a scroll
>   bar.

Reference Links for detail clarification

[www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)